# Fluid clients get out of sync when server is rebooted

Tags: fluid-framework

I got the HelloWorld example to run fine. But once I stopped & restarted the server the clients got out of sync--even when I set a consistent document (i.e. `location.hash = "12345"`).

Setting `createNew=false` broke the app (no dice--literally).

And I get a lot of repeating errors:

```
[start:server] error: Connect Document error: {} {"messageMetaData":{"documentId":"1608237690408","tenantId":"tinylicious"},"label":"winston","timestamp":"2020-12-17T20:45:13.160Z"}
[start:server] info: Disconnect of 60c72737-3e05-4bc7-bf9b-f7ca6439a431 from room {"messageMetaData":{"documentId":"1608237690408","tenantId":"tinylicious"},"label":"winston","timestamp":"2020-12-17T20:45:13.161Z"}
```

Does Fluid support this scenario?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The tinylicious service *could* support turning off & on with durable data, but it's really meant to be a test service. When you restart the service, you'll probably want to pick a new documentID.

`createNew` is a more interesting story. The Hello World application is somewhat contrived example. In general, the app developer will get a signal from the user that a new document should be created. Think about Google Docs.

"Create New Google Doc" -> `createNew === true`

"Open existing Google Doc" -> `createNew === false`

However, for the Hello World scenario, we want to have as little code as possible. We certainly don't want to write out a whole document management schema. So we rely on a nifty little trick: If you paste in a URL with a specific documentID we assume you are loading an existing document, otherwise we will make a new one for you.

That's what the below is doing!

You'll see the effects in the URLs, which look something like this: http://localhost:8080/#1608592296522

```js
let createNew = false;
if (location.hash.length === 0) {
    createNew = true;
    location.hash = Date.now().toString();
}
const documentId = location.hash.substring(1);
document.title = documentId;
```

Comment: OK. I was looking for a "test" example that I could battle test (i.e. crash/reboot). Also, I suppose to be "durable" we would need a db or something.  I don't see any db in the examples.

Comment: The routerlicious server is a better fit. It’s well tested, scalable, and quite durable. I believe the devops flows could use some more work still.